# How to temporarily disable XSS protection in modern browsers for testing?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

Is it possible to temporarily disable the XSS protection found in modern browsers for testing purposes?

I'm trying to explain to a co-worker what happens when one sends this to an XSS-vulnerable web form:

```
<script>alert("Danger");</script>
```

However, it appears that both Chrome and Firefox are preventing the XSS popup. Can I disable this protection so I can fully see the results of my actions?

Comment: I don't think any browser would block that script in case it really is served as part of the html sent from the server.

Comment: @Delta the browser usually blocks it if it sent from the user and also returned by the server, not if it is just sent from the server. e.g. `MyPage.aspx?id=<script>alert('s');</alert>` would be sent as the request, but if any part of the code appears in script in the response it may be blocked (i.e. not executed) by the browser.

Answer (score 27):

In Chrome there is a flag with which you can start the browser. If you start the browser with this flag, you can do what you want:

```
--disable-web-security
```

Comment: @Zachary K: Is this for Chromium only? Maybe no longer possible? http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r-QGNb0MACo

Comment: In Chrome 65.0.3325.181: “*You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security.*” The XSS auditor is *not* disabled. `--disable-xss-auditor` is still supported and works.

Answer (score 22):

For the convenience of those who don't know....

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security

Use the above as the path of the shortcut

Comment: This will only work when all chrome instances are closed before starting chrome with these commands. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679399/does-disable-web-security-work-in-chrome-anymore

Answer (score 17):

If you only wan't to disable XSS you should use `--disable-xss-auditor`. A complete argument would be something like:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-xss-auditor

Make sure all chrome.exe processes are killed before running the command or it will have no effect. You can also pass more arguments if you wish, for example I often use a proxy argument because I don't want to enable a proxy for my entire system.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-xss-auditor --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the user to another local web page when the form is submitted and print the infected data. Chrome will not detect that.

Hint: You can use sessions / cookies to store the infected data between the 2 pages.

**Example in PHP:**

index.php

```
<?php    
    setcookie('infected', $_POST['infected']);

    if($_POST['infected'])
        header('location: show.php');
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" />
    <p>
        Username: <input type="text" name="infected" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
    </p>
</form>
```

show.php

```
echo $_COOKIE['data'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is use of disable argument temporary?  In limited testing it seems permanent.  **XSS-Auditor remains disabled** in Chrome windows started without any xss-auditor argument. To turn back on use "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-xss-auditor

Answer (score -1):

I know this doesn't fix it but it may just need a message on the sites for now until Google fixes it. something like, "If using Chrome you may experience....". I found that even though I get the error screen that the content does in fact go in the database. I just hit back to get back into the site. Then go to the dashboard and it is there. Pain in the ass but is a work around that doesn't need to set sites back.