# Does --disable-web-security work in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cors, httprequest, websecurity

I'm trying to do a simple test without changing any server-side code involving a [cross-domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) [AJAX call](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), and I was wondering if it's possible to use [`--disable-web-security`](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/27241967?hl=en) anymore. It seems to not work on Chrome 28.

I haven't used it since Chrome version 21; has this feature been dropped?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check your windows task manager and make sure you kill all chrome processes before running the command.

Comment: That did it.  I just forgot to kill one chrome process.

Comment: With the current Chrome it doesn't matter. I am browsing with enabled security while e2e testing with disabled security in a different window using Karma...

Comment: Get call happening in the network tab but it is blocking post call with web security disabled. If you find any solution for the same please let here know.
Thanks

Comment: Similarly on MacOS, remember closing all the Chrome windows alone will not fully quit Chrome— you also need to go to the application menu or icon and select "quit".

Answer (score 44):

The new tag for recent Chrome and Chromium browsers is :

```
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my\data
```

Comment: This is working, using only --disable-web-security doesn't.

Comment: let's say I want to enable web security again. How can I do it?

Comment: The `user-data-dir` flag is now mandatory when trying to disable web security, because it effectively launches a second Chrome "profile".  You can run a normal ("with" web security) profile by just launching Chrome with no command line flags, and this "good" session can run at the same time as the unprotected session.

Comment: It isn't working for me. It still says it can't load a file due to strict mime type checking for module scripts, "per HTML spec".

Answer (score 28):

Try this :

**Windows:**

Run below commands in `CMD` to start a new instance of chrome browser with disabled security

Go to Chrome folder:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Run below command:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my-chrome-data\data
```

**MAC OS:**

Run this command in terminal:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_sess_1" --disable-web-security
```

Hope this will help both Windows & Mac users!

Comment: Mac one does not work. Almost tried everything after first trying the above one.
--disable-site-isolation-trials -> does not work
--disable-gpu -> does not work
Tried opera also -> no luck

Comment: Which MAC OS you have ?

Comment: im on catolina, any luck?

Comment: Mac command works for me on Big Sur. Not sure if it's a factor, but Chrome was not running when I entered the command. For what it's worth: Chrome then acted as if it were being installed for the first time.

Comment: How to do in Linux?

Answer (score 16):

This flag worked for me at v30.0.1599.101 m
[image]

The warning "You are using an unsupported command-line flag" can be ignored. The flag still works (as of Chrome v86).

Answer (score 11):

This should work. You may save the following in a batch file:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security
pause
```

Comment: got a mac version?

Comment: In case anybody finds this in 2020 and beyond: this is no longer valid.  `disable-web-security` now has no effect if you don't also specify `user-data-dir` -- you can't disable web security on your default profile.

Answer (score 4):

Open target location of chrome and navigate through cmd 
type

> chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my\dat

Answer (score 3):

Just create this batch file and run it on windows. It basically would kill all chrome instances and then would start chrome with disabling security. Save the following script in batch file say ***.bat and double click on it.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security –-allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: Says invalid agrument start

Comment: Please try this in a file batch (I should have introduced a new line before start):
TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security
pause

Comment: I did it in a batch file. No worries though. I can open up task manager and kill the process tree for chrome

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Chrome App Launcher. You can usually see it in your toolbar. It runs as a second instance of chrome, but unlike the browser, it auto-runs so is going to be running whenever you start your PC. Even though it isn't a browser view, it is a chrome instance which is enough to prevent your arguments from taking effect. Go to your task manager and you will probably have to kill 2 chrome processes.

Answer (score 1):

### Automated solution for Windows 10

1. Right-click on Chrome icon > right-click Google Chrome > Properties

[image: Windows 10 toolbar > right-click Chrome icon > right-click Google Chrome > Properties]

2. Shortcut > Target > "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\ChromeDevSession"

[image: Shortcut > Target > "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\ChromeDevSession"]

Notes:

- Your file path for `chrome.exe` may vary.
- Also, the `--user-data-dir` flag is required, and its file path may vary. Besides `C:\ChromeDevSession`, another possible location is `~/chromeTemp`

3. **Now Chrome always has its web security disabled :-)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this:
Kill chrome from task Manager First. In Windows - Right Click (or Shift+right click, in-case of taskbar) on Chrome Icon. Select Properties. In "Target" text-box, add `--disable-web-security` flag.

So text in text-box should look like

```
C:\Users\njadhav\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security
```

Click Ok and launch chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't run --disable-web-security and a normal chrome in parallel it's probably a good solution to use Opera for --disable-web-security

Here is how to create a launcher for opera on windows. By the way, Opera has the same debugging tools as chrome!

http://www.opera.com/

```
:: opera-browse-dangerously.bat
cd c:\Program Files\Opera\
launcher.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\opera-dev"
```

PS: Opera doesn't display any notification when started without web-security

Answer (score 0):

just run this command from command prompt and it will launch chrome instance with CORS disabled:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```