# XSS DOM vulnerable

Tags: xss

I tested site for vulnerables (folder /service-contact) and possible XSS DOM issue came up (using Kali Linux, Vega and XSSER). However, i tried to manually test url with 'alert' script to make sure it's vulnerable. I used

[www.babyland.nl/service-contact/alert("test")](http://www.babyland.nl/service-contact/%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22test%22)%3C/script%3E)
No alert box/pop-up was shown, only the html code showed up in contact form box.

I am not sure i used the right code (i'm a rookie) or did the right interpretation. Server is Apache, using javascript/js.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't appear that that site is vulnerable to XSS (at least through the vector you suggested). Sounds like a false positive in your scanner.

Answer (score 1):

This is Not Vulnerable to XSS, Whatever you are writing in the URL is Coming in Below Form section ( Vraag/opmerking ) . And the Double Quotes (") are Escaped. If you try another Payload like `<script>alert(/xss/)</script>` That Also won't work, Because this is Not Reflecting neither Storing. You will see output as a Text in Vraag/opmerking. Don't Rely on Online Scanners, Test Manually, For DOM Based XSS ..Check Sink and Sources and Analyze them.

Answer (score 0):

The tool is right. There is a XSS-Vulnerability on the site, but the proof of concept (PoC) code is wrong. The content of a <textarea> can only contain [character data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) (see [<textarea> description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)). So your `<script>alert("test")</script>` is interpreted as text and not as HTML code. But you can close the <textarea> tag and insert the javascript code after that.

Here is the working PoC URL:

`https://www.babyland.nl/service-contact/</textarea><script>alert("test")</script>`

which is rendered as:

`<textarea rows="" cols="" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea<script>alert("test")</script></textarea>`

A little note to testing for XSS injection: Chrome/Chromium has a XSS protection. So this code doesn't exploit in this browser. For manual testing you can use Firefox or run Chrome with: `--disable-web-security` ([see this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679399/does-disable-web-security-work-in-chrome-anymore) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/does-google-chrome-protect-against-cross-site-scripting-xss) for more information).