# Chrome --disable-web-security no longer works

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain

We have been using the following to open Google Crome without a Cross-Origin limitation for debug purposes for some time. Yesterday it stopped working on all of our Windows computers.

chrome.exe https://"www.testsite.com" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="d:/tempchromedata"

Current version of Chrome is Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/128511

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does --disable-web-security work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679399/does-disable-web-security-work-in-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently if you add the following it works
--disable-site-isolation-trials

Comment: For me (Chrome 73.0.3683.86) this gives the following notification: `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-site-isolation-trials. Stability and security will suffer.` What did work however was adding: `--disable-features=IsolateOrigins`

Comment: I set '--disable-web-security',
   '--user-data-dir=D:\temp\',
   '--disable-site-isolation-trials', in chrome.dart, in debug mode use localhost:54321 i faced with : You are using an unsupported command-line flag: —disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer' and Ajax calls has been bloked

Answer (score 0):

thanks Thomas Mulder, best comment ever

for me, to allow javascript to access content in iframe of different origin, with Chromium Version 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) built on Debian 11.6, running on Debian 11.4 (64-bit):

chromium --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=$HOME/tmp/user-data  --disable-site-isolation-trials

... worked, I needed all three options. The javascript was in a file://xxx.html (and gets "null" origin); the iframe within xxx.html had a "http://localhost:8383" origin in my particular case.