# How to enable web security in Chrome after disabling it?

Tags: google-chrome, websecurity

I did the `__disable-web-security` in Terminal on Mac. Do I need to enable it again? Or does it enable by itself after restart?

If I need to enable it again, how do I do that? I searched everywhere, but didn't find.

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679399/does-disable-web-security-work-in-chrome-anymore/36939693

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I see that just says how to disable. I need to enable web security again, cos it is already disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `chrome://version` and look at the **Command Line**. If the command line argument is still there, you should restart chrome and then launch it normally (without the flag).

A bit more context: "Flag" refers to two slightly different concepts in Chrome:

1. Any command line argument that starts with a `--` (as opposed to an argument that names a URL or a file, for example).
2. The list of toggles available at `chrome://flags`.

Any arguments added manually to the command line will only persist until you quit Chrome. On the other hand, the toggles set at `chrome://flags` will persist until they are reset. (To further blur this, invoking `chrome://restart` will preserve the command line flags.)

This particular flag makes its presence fairly obvious, with a banner:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer.

So it should hopefully be clear whether the flag is present (and also why this is the sort of flag that can't be persisted at `chrome://flags`).

The flags set in #2 are delimited in Chrome's command line by the `--flags-switches-begin`…`--flags-switches-end` section. Arguments outside of that section are coming from somewhere other than `chrome://flags` (namely, from the command line, except in the case of Chrome OS and Android, which have their own startup procedures).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me into that direction. There is no command line argument there. But I use a 2016 version of Chrome 49.0.2623.112. Did that command line argument appear on that old version too?

Comment: Even if you use a flag that chrome does not recognize, it will show up there, you can try it with `--random-made-up-flag`. So if the flag is not there, it's not there.

Comment: Oh it's called flag? In the chrome://version, it says both --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end. So is it off or on then?

Comment: @jl001 Added some more context.

Comment: Great! Thanks you so much for your help!!