# cors(cors policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check) error in angular 7

Tags: php, angular7

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.30/v1w/?tag=login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible solutions

1. You need to add CORS headers at your PHP end. Solution is provided in another question [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)
2. If you do not want to add CORS, which I recommend when for your production environment, you can setup a reverse proxy using nginx or httpd such that both your http-request and html files are served from same url base
3. You can also temporarily disable CORS check on browser. Answered here: [Does --disable-web-security work in Chrome anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679399/does-disable-web-security-work-in-chrome-anymore/36939693)
4. You can also use chrome extension or firefox extension which can disable CORS check for certain domains. Example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US