# How chrome browser(v87) to disable cors check

Tags: google-chrome, security

i have tried below methods:

**methods 1**

```sh
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/temp/chrome_dev"
```

**result**

can not solve this problem.

**methods 2**

add `--disable-site-isolation-trials` arguement

```sh
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/temp/chrome_dev"
```

**result**

chrome will infinite reqeust for same page.

#### my platform

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

#### chrome version info

```
Google Chrome   87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 8.7.220.29
Flash   32.0.0.465 /home/sheng/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/32.0.0.465/libpepflashplayer.so
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Comment: Per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238150/421195), `google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/temp/chrome_dev"` should work, if 1)  directory ` `/temp/chrome_dev` actually exists, and 2) you've terminated *ALL* other instances of Chrome.  If it's not working, please "Edit" your post with your JS code, run in Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab, and post the HTTP error(s)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I face the same problem.